# Will I be eligible for Windows 8 upgrade?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8-preview

I finally got off Windows XP after 9 years on it. I am just getting to play with Windows 7 and am considering purchasing the Professional edition very soon.

Will I be eligible for an upgrade to Windows 8 once it comes out?

Comment: Eligible for an upgrade...  as in for a free upgrade? They haven't released any info on this yet. As far as hardware: if you can run 7 you can probably run 8

Comment: Something similar to what they did when Vista was released: providing free upgrades to Vista for people who are purchasing XP machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They could possibly some time after the release provide free upgrades to people that buy Windows 7; however, in general buying Windows 7 does not make you eligibile for a free upgrade to Windows 8. You can however buy Windows 8 later  and easily upgrade through it, at least when they don't ridiculously change their upgrade path. But as they share the same underlying structure, upgrading is possible.

I would suggest you to wait till the release of Windows 8 before upgrading if you are on a budget...

Please note that there are upgrade versions which cost cheaper than the full version.
But they only allow you to upgrade and not do a (re)installation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Tom. Even if I had to buy Windows 7 now and later want to upgrade when Windows 8 comes out, would the upgrade cost somewhat lesser than a new Windows 8 purchase? I don't remember how it was done for XP/Vista transition.

Comment: @Kishor: They do, compare [the upgrade](http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Windows-Home-Premium-Upgrade/dp/B002DHLUWK) to the [full version](http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Windows-7-Home-Premium/dp/B002DHGMK0/ref=pd_cp_sw_3).

Comment: ie: you _probably will_ be eligible to buy an upgrade edition, which will _likely_ be cheaper then the full version, but _will probably not_ get the upgrade for free. But at this point anything you hear is little better than pure conjecture. As your stock broker might tell you, past performance is a poor indicator of future results.  Microsoft may decide to go a whole new direction on pricing for Windows 8, perhaps to counter Apple's $29 upgrade strategy. We just don't know.

Comment: The only thing certain is death and taxes. . .

Answer (score 1):

Last time, [when Windows 7 pricing was announced](http://gadgetwise.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/06/25/pricing-for-windows-7-announced/) **four months** before release:

- Buying a **new PC** with Vista, it would be upgraded to 7 for free.
- You could pre-order Windows 7 starting then, and at an extra discount (upgrade or full) for a few weeks after the announcement.

Comment: I am most certainly interested in this approach, but the official Windows 8 release date is too far for my consideration.